# PHP Issue to create multidimensional array

Tags: php

I have an array

```
 [0] => Array
      (
        [0] => Parameter_Key1
        [1] => ParameterA
        [2] => Parameter_Value1
        [3] => Parameter_Value2
    )

 [1] => Array
    (
        [0] =>
        [1] => ParameterB
        [2] => Parameter_Value1
        [3] => Parameter_Value2
    )

  [2] => Array
    (
        [0] =>
        [1] => ParameterC
        [2] => Parameter_Value1
        [3] => Parameter_Value2
    )
 [3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Parameter_Key2
        [1] => ParameterD
        [2] => Parameter_Value1
        [3] => Parameter_Value2
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] =>
        [1] => ParameterE
        [2] => Parameter_Value1
        [3] => Parameter_Value2
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] =>
        [1] => ParameterF
        [2] => Parameter_Value1
        [3] => Parameter_Value2
    )
```

I am trying to create a new array like below:
 Parameter_Key1=>ParameterA{"Parameter_Value1", Parameter_Value2}, ParameterB{"Parameter_Value1", Parameter_Value2}, ParameterC{"Parameter_Value1", Parameter_Value2}

Parameter_Key2=>ParameterD{"Parameter_Value1", Parameter_Value2}, ParameterE{"Parameter_Value1", Parameter_Value2}, ParameterF{"Parameter_Value1", Parameter_Value2}

So in above output there are two Keys named as Parameter_Key1 and Parameter_Key2
I have to add all the values to Parameter_Key1 until i found another value at 0th index (in subarray). If i found 2nd element in 0th index like "Parameter_Key2" i need to add as a new key value pair.
Can any one help please?
Sorry for my indentation issue.

Comment: Array (
  [Parameter_Key1] => Array
  (
   [ParameterA]=>{Parameter_Value1,Parameter_Value2},
   [ParameterB]=>{Parameter_Value1,Parameter_Value2},
   [ParameterC]=>{Parameter_Value1,Parameter_Value2}
  )

  [Parameter_Key2] => Array
  (
   [ParameterD]=>{Parameter_Value1,Parameter_Value2},
   [ParameterE]=>{Parameter_Value1,Parameter_Value2},
   [ParameterF]=>{Parameter_Value1,Parameter_Value2} 
        )
)

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick and dirty answer. If the internal order of the input array is different from the numeric order foreach won't work...

```
$in=[['k1','A','v1','v2'],['','B','v1','v2'],['','C','v1','v2'],['k2','D','v1','v2'],['','E','v1','v2']];//your input
$out=[];
$key='';
//var_dump($in);
foreach($in as $p) {
    if($p[0]!='') $key=$p[0];
    $out[$key][$p[1]]=[$p[2],$p[3]];
}
var_dump($out);
```

Comment: Thank you jh711 for your quick answer!!
I just have a quick doubt:  if loop does not have braces, you mean to have scope for current line only?
Also i am getting error while running this code: 
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in on line:

 $out[$key][$p[1]]=[$p[2],$p[3]];

Comment: The if for one statement only. Many people don't like it, because this can happen:[code]if (false) ;echo('what');[/code]. The syntax error is strange. I took it directly from 3v4l: https://3v4l.org/WEDCM

Comment: You could try `=array($p[1],$p[2])`. But that should only make a difference for really old PHP versions. And lines 1 and 2 should throw errors there.